# How can I access a volatile variable in another thread JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to access variables from multiple running threads.

I have a main class that starts up 2 threads, a producer and a consumer.

the PRODUCER thread reads a binary file. For each line in that binary file the producer thread creates an object from it, and passes that object to the consumer thread through a blockingqueue.

the CONSUMER then takes that object passed in through a blocking queue and outputs the values of the fields in that object to a text file.

sometimes there are errors in the binary file that the producer thread is reading from.

when there are too many errors in the binary file, I want the consumer thread to change the extension of the txt file that it outputs to .err

My problem: I dont know how to modify a value from a producer thread in a consumer thread. Ive been reading that I could use a volatile field. But I dont know what is the proper way to use it between threads.

Here is a very shortened and less complex example of my code :

```
public class Main 
{

   private volatile static boolean tooManyErrors= false; 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
   {

        BlockingQueue<binaryObject> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(null);

        binaryObject poison = null;

        new Thread(new Producer(tooManyErrors, queue, poison)).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(tooManyErrors, queue, poison)).start();

    }
}

public class Producer implements Runnable 
{

    private final BlockingQueue<binaryObject> queue;
    private final binaryObject POISON;
    private boolean tooManyErrors;

    private int errorsCounter = 0;

    public Producer(boolean tooManyErrors, BlockingQueue<binaryObject> queue, 
    binaryObject POISON) 
    {
        this.tooManyErrors = tooManyErrors;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.POISON = POISON;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {

        try 
        {
            process();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        finally 
        {
            while (true) 
        {
                try 
                {
                    queue.put(POISON);
                    break;
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    //...
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void process() throws InterruptedException 
    {
       //here is where all the logic to read the file and create
       //the object goes in. counts the number of errors in the file
       //if too many errors, want to change the tooManyErrors to true       

       if(errorsCounter > 100)
       {
          tooManyErrors = true;
       }

    }

}


public class Consumer implements Runnable 
{

    private final BlockingQueue<binaryObject> queue;
    private final binaryObject POISON;
    private boolean tooManyErrors;

    //variable with extension name
    private String extension;

    public Consumer(boolean tooManyErrors, BlockingQueue<Integer> queue, 
    binaryObject POISON) 
    {
        this.tooManyErrors = tooManyErrors;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.POISON = POISON;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {

        try 
        {
            while (true) 
            {
                binaryObject take = queue.take();
                process(take);

                // if this is a poison pill, break, exit
                if (take == POISON) 
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }

    private void process(Integer take) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        //this is where all the logic goes that takes the binaryObject
        //grabs all the fields from it such as binaryObject.getFileName,
        //happens. It then outputs a text file with all the fields grabbed
        //from the object. If the producer thread found too many errors
        // I want the extension changed to .err instead of .txt
        // I dont know how to do that

       if(tooManyErrors == false)
       {
           extension = ".txt";

           createFile(extension);
       }
       else
       {
           extension = ".err";

           createFile(extension);
       }
    }

   private void createFile(String extension)
   {
     //...
   }

}
```

Comment: since the `Consumer` does not have a reference to the `Producer` - i don't think there is a way. Either your `Main` class has the `tooManyErrors` field, or both the consumer/rproducer have it. there's no need to have it everywhere, as that will only result in shadowing.

Comment: I see what would I have to do to be able to see that value from the consume thread? pass in a reference to the producer thread as in        

new Thread(new Consumer(Producer, tooManyErrors, queue, poison)).start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, a couple of things here.  I assume there is only one producer and one consumer.  If that is the case you can mark the classes  producer and consumer as `static`.  If you mark the class as `static`, only one instance of its fields will exist - it will be a singleton.  You can mark any of the fields of the producer and consumer as not private, and the simply access the fields.  `somethingINeed = Producer.fieldThatIsNotPrivate` from inside the consumer and vice versa.

Another alternative would be to keep a handle to the object you want and pass that into the constructor.

```
Producer p = new Producer(tooManyErrors, queue, poison);
Consumer c = new Consumer(tooManyErrors, queue, poison);
p.setConsumer(c);
c.setProducer(p);
new Thread(p).start();
new Thread(c).start();
```

And you could create accessors for whatever fields need to share information.